# How to create a repository where each change requires the agreement of both partners?

Tags: github

Two partners are building a software project. They want that each change made by one partner must be approved by the other partner.

If one of them opens a GitHub repository and makes the other one a collaborator, then both of them can change the repository without consent from the other partner. They can also ask for consent by doing the change in a branch and then doing a pull-request on the branch, but the system does not force them to do it, so they might forget.

If one of them opens a GitHub repository and does NOT make the other partner a collaborator, then the second partner must make a pull request for each change, but the first partner can still make changes without the other partner reviewing them.

Is it possible to create a repository such that, each change by one of the partners only becomes public after the other partner approves it?

Comment: And this is not a job for GitHub (which is "the usual tasks for the usual people), but for own infrastructure

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such feature exists yet in Github AFAIK. But I think something like this works.

- Create another account either a dummy or a bot account
- Create repository from the dummy/bot account
- Since you both are not collaborators, you need to fork the repository and issue pull requests no matter what.

There is a minor correction to what you said though

`If one of them opens a GitHub repository and does not make the other partner a collaborator, then the second partner must make a pull request for each change, but the first partner can still make changes without the other partner reviewing them.`

If you make your partner a collaborator then he too can push code to `master` without a pull request.

PS: Honestly, I don't think this question is supposed to be on StackOverflow.